# Unable to connect to remote host

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

When i try to do

```
lynx -dump http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=kan&password=abc&to=[recipient%20no]&text=[text]
```

This is the error that came up.

```
Looking up 127.0.0.1:13013
Making HTTP connection to 127.0.0.1:13013
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.
lynx: Can't access startfile http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=kan&password=abc&to=[recipient%20no]&text=[text]
```

Comment: please provide some additional information, such as the software you are using to try and send these sms's

Answer (score 1):

The error message points to the fact that it is unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:13013 so the best place to start is to see if you actually have a service listening on that port.

What service are you using to try and send these sms's and is that service running?

issue a netstat -l -n and check to see if you have a item that says

```
proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:13013          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

If you dont, then the service you are attempting to use is not started, or is started but using another port. You will need to start it or make sure you are using the correct port.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are trying to use [kannel](http://www.kannel.org/). It is not listening to that port. Check whether it is running, and whether it is configured to listen to port 13013.